# Damn I can't do it

Tags: vimrc

Here is my .profile (macs don't usually bother with .bashrc)

```
export VIMINIT="let $MYVIMRC='/Users/user/userbits/future.vimrc' | source $MYVIMRC"
source /Users/user/userbits/future.source`
```

Explanation: `/Users` is where users go on macs. It's like `/home` in Linux. I've unimaginatively called my user `user`. The folder where I want all his things is called `/Users/user/userbits`. And I want his `.vimrc`in there too, renamed as `future.vimrc`.

The second line of the code sources a file called `/Users/user/userbits/future.source` which is kind of like my `.bashrc` - it sets up lots of functions and netrw things. With a `.vimrc` in a normal place (eg. `/Users/user/.vimrc') everything works fine.

But whats going wrong when I rename my`.vimrc` to `future.vimrc` and put it in `/Users/user/userbits`?

The last poster seemed to have it so right, and I've been going through his/her suggested reading for hours. Why can't I do it?

Comment: backslashes are important

Answer (score 0):

Yesss! It works. I thought the backslashes were to make the code more readable, but then you inspired me to turn my phone on its side. Here is my finished . profile for anyone interested in this:

```
export VIMINIT="let \$MYVIMRC='/Users/user/user bits/future.vimrc' | source \$MYVIMRC"
source /Users/user/userbits/future.source
```

(So happy. Thank you Mass)